# What is the best expression of a particular nickname?

Tags: characters, culture

I am wondering what the best way to express a particular nickname might be.  Because my name in real life is *very* common, I sometimes use various permutation of 'Shewolf' instead for various internet usernames (drawn from a childhood comic character).  I thought it might be nice to use it in Chinese as well, but I want to be careful of a potential cultural faux pas and/or nonsense-making.

My initial thoughts were 女狼 or 母狼, but there is also 牝 for the female of an animal species.

Which of the above, or something else entirely, would match best?  I'm mainly checking to make sure I don't accidentally call myself something untoward. Or if I should abandon the idea entirely.

Comment: Also - since this might be too open-ended and/or subjective I went to visit the chat room first, but it appears to be frozen :/

Comment: Sounded really weird as Chinese names.

Comment: @lilysirius Weird as a real name or weird as an internet username-type-thing? It doesn't need to pass muster as a real name, but if it's *still* weird as an internet name I'll just skip it.

Comment: Weird in every usage you mentioned.

Comment: Gotcha!  I'm glad I asked then, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As a Chinese netizen for more than ten years, I have never seen anyone calling themself a "母狼". It is true that only animals are uncommonly used to describe humans in Chinese than in English(except for special occasions or jokes between specific relationships). Especially you want to use "she" in front (With "狼" attached, it seems like an expression of impoliteness towards women). But if you add some words (related to the game, or humorous), this "impolite" feeling is gone. For example, you call yourself "狼外婆" (also related to "female wolves"), the fairy tale character that almost everyone knows. Hope this answer will help you ~

Answer (score 1):

Scrip the idea or try "狼妞", if you like "wolf" that much and want to reveal your female sex.

IMO, "狼妞" is cuter than "女狼" or "母狼" and more associable.

Comment: I hadn't run across 妞 before, good to know that might work better.  Lots of options from the answers here thank you!

Comment: :) :) You are welcome. It is quite popular in northern China to call their little girls "妞". In the south, "妹" is the choice.

Answer (score 1):

[女郎](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/23934) /nv3 **lang2** /: young woman; maiden; girl;

[狼](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/1639)/**lang2**/ :wolf

狼 and 郎 are homonyms, therefore,  女狼 (wolf Medien/ wolf girl) would be an interesting nickname.

If you think it is too plain,  try 俏女郎 (pretty girl) --> **俏女狼** (pretty wolf girl)

Also, the counterpart of Shewolf in Chinese is 母老虎(tigress), which is a common term in Chinese:

> [母老虎](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%AF%8D%E8%80%81%E8%99%8E/66916) :colloquialism. Usually refers to a 潑婦 (shrew)

Comment: I hadn't thought of tigress ... interesting idea. Hmm

Answer (score 1):

> Shewolf

well, an interesting nickname

since “狼” is composed by “犬” + “良”; so you may consider these:

**姬良犬**

”姬” means “praised description of female (女子的美稱)

**坤良犬**

“坤” implied “female”, in the book of change (「坤」也可表示女性。《易‧繫辭上》：「坤道成女。」)

directly using the charatcer “狼” in a name is, . . . trigger negative feeling. that, decompose it into “良犬” is an better approach, imo

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! If the decomposition avoids negative connotations that sounds good to me, glad to avoid negative feelings